# I can't run Realm project with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

Hi every one could you please help me to fix that error:

I use android studio so i found this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/rw-performance-comparison
So my probleme is : I can't run this project I really tried a lot of time before asking you.

Comment: `unclear what you are asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.`

Comment: ok,I download the project from the link above so I can't run it using ANdroid Studio, if you could try juste to run it and give the details for exemple: add android studio project-> ...->..->

thanks my friend

Answer (score 0):

Christian from Realm here.
You are trying to compile an old branch that is not maintained anymore. If you are interested in performance numbers I would encourage you to write your own performance test. Then you would also be able to test the stuff you care about instead of looking at generalised numbers.

Comment: Tnx Bro ^^ but I need only one test with numbers to present it to my boss and after i will try with him to migrate From SQLite to RealM then i'll create my own test